# Exporting data from cell to Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, cell

Let's say I have a cell named `data` like this:

```
data{1} = vector1; 
data{2} = vector2; 
... 
data{n} = vectorn;
```

All vectors (with numerical values)  in `data` have the same 1xN size.

Now, I want to export this data file into an .xlsx document where each row is a vector and I want to label each column. The result should be something like this:

```
  label1         label2        ...       labelN

vector1(1,1)   vector1(1,2)    ...     vector1(1,N)

  ...              ...         ...         ...

vectorn(1,1)   vectorn(1,2)    ...     vectorn(1,N)
```

I tried to do this using:

```
n=10;
N=5;
for i=1:n
  data{i}=rand(1,N);
end
filename='test.xlsx';
xlswrite(filename,data)
```

but my .xlsx file comes with all the data from `data` in just one row. And I don't know how to do the labels.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [**`vertcat`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html), [**`num2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), [**`sprintf`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), [**`strsplit`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [**`xlswrite`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) as follows:

```
modified_data = num2cell(vertcat(data{:}));     % Converting 1xn cell into nxN cell

% Generating Column Headers as specified in the question
col_header = strsplit(sprintf('label%d ' , 1:N));
col_header = col_header(1:end-1);
% If N is not much high number (e.g; if N=5), you can input Column Headers as: 
% col_header = {'label1','label2','label3','label4','label5'};

filename='test.xlsx';                           % Name of the excel file to be written
xlswrite(filename,[col_header; modified_data]); % Writing the excel file
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you call `rand(1,N)` together in one cell (`data{i}`). For each value in its own cell you have to create a nxN matrix of cells, which is easiest done if you transfrom the entire matirx:

```
n=10;
N=5;
  data=rand(n,N);
  celldata=num2cell(data);
filename='test.xlsx';
xlswrite(filename,celldata);
```

otherwise you have to make two loops but thats not so great performancewise

Comment: The OP has data in the form of  1xn cell. This answer doesn't say anything about conversion. Also no information is provided about column headers. So this is not an answer